# Weird segfault on variable assignment

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

I have a weird segfault with the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void bugtest(char **output)
{
    *output = malloc(10);
    if (! *output)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed\n");
        return;
    }
    memset(*output, 0, 10);

    for (char i = 0; i < 6; i += 2)
    {
        *output[i / 2] = i;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char *output = NULL;
    bugtest(&output);

    printf("%s\n", output);
    return 0;
}
```

`*output` is not NULL but it crashes at `*output[i / 2] = i;`. Does anyone know why?

Comment: `*output[i / 2]` -> `(*output)[i / 2]`

Comment: BTW: `printf("%s\n", output);` is rather pointless, it won't display anything. You should do this: `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) printf("%d\n", output[i]);`

Answer (score 4):

`*output[i / 2]` Operator precedence. Should have been `(*output)[i / 2]`.

Instead of dragging that ugly pointer-to-pointer across your whole function (and causing bugs because you do), then do this:

```
void bugtest(char **output)
{
    char* result = malloc(10);
    if (result == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed\n");
        return;
    }
    memset(result, 0, 10);

    for (char i = 0; i < 6; i += 2)
    {
        result[i / 2] = i;
    }
    
    *output = result;
}
```

Unrelated to your bug, it doesn't make any sense to print the symbol values 0 to 6 as a string here: `printf("%s\n", output);`. Symbol `0`, the null terminator, is particularly troublesome since it will just stop the printing. Perhaps you meant to print integer values?

Comment: I found this page https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence and I'm wondering how does the compiler interprets `*output[i / 2]` here?

Comment: @daisy Postfix > prefix operators so you get `*(output[i / 2])`, which gives pointer arithmetic on a `char**` type before you dereference, not what you wanted.

Comment: The precedence table shows precedence 1 for `[]` and precedence 2 for `*` (pointer dereferencement). Therefore `*output[i / 2]`  is equivalent to `*(output[i / 2]`)`: first the array subscipt `[]`, then the dereferencement (`* `).